# Copy data from rows in Worksheet to another worksheet based on quantity selected

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm a Graphic Designer by trade and while I know basic Excel this is getting into foreign territory for me.

So I have been tasked with putting together our company's product price list (with +800+ products that are all broken into categories/tabs) into a version that users can select quantities per item and see a running list on the page of their total. No problem, I have this figured out.

Each item has a column for a part number, description, price, and quantity...with the quantity defaulted to zero. I need to get this so that if user wants an item they can change the quantity to whatever they want, and press the add/update purchase order button and have this values of that item's row add to a separate sheet. Additionally, if they were to change value to zero and press the button again, it would remove the item.

So right now each worksheet in the book is like this:

[image]

Ideally it would be great to just have one macro/button that once a user enters whatever quantity of item(s) they want, it would copy the row (but as column-order G B C F H) to a sheet in that book named "Purchase Order". If the user changes a quantity of an item to 0, and reclicks the button, it removes said row from the other worksheet. This would need to work through the 30+ other tabs, and append the rows below already entered values as the user continues to add products to their purchase order (starting on B22 on the Purchase Order worksheet)

My concerns are adding/deleting products in the future/other staff having to update this and not needing to do crazy changes to the macro if, say I need to add 5 more products to a tab.

I will take ANY help, insight, direction, or guidance anyone can shed on this issue. I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I don't know if I understood well your question, but here's what I'm thinking: You could create 2 buttons on the Worksheet, one with a big "+" on it, the other with a "-" and link them to 2 different subroutines. 
  
  Those items could be positioned at the end or beginning of a product row. Right click on the buttons, go to properties and be sure that those are dependant on cell position and size. 
  The "+" one could check if your "Purchase Order" is currently open (in case it isn't, could create a new one), and add all the content on the same row in the new worksheet (you can use `Application.Caller` to address the buttons and `.Top` / `.Left` to address its row/column).
  
   Naturally you'll want to search if the name of the product is already in the "Purchase Order", in that case increase quantity, otherwise copy all the row. 
  Same thing with the "-" button eliminating the product row if quantity is 0. The fun part: you can create 2 buttons and the macros, and then copy the buttons for each row, since they each address rows on their right/left!

EDIT:

```
Sub Add()

Dim Button_cell_row As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet
Dim ProductName As String
Dim i As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set Target = Workbooks("Purchase_Order.xls").worksheets(1) ' Here you need to choose the file (Workbook) and the Worksheet (Tab) you want

Button_cell_row = ws.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row

Do Until IsEmpty(Target.Cells(i,4)) ' for example your product name is in the 4th column
    If Target.Cells(i,4) = ProductName Then
        Target.Cells(i,7) = cInt(Target.Cells(i,7)) + 1 ' say that the quantity is stored in the 7th cell
    Exit Do
    End If
    i = i+1
Loop

If IsEmpty(Target.Cells(i,4)) Then ' meaning that the whole sheet has been searched but there's no product with a similar name on the whole "i" loop-range
' in this case "i" is now the index of your first empty row
    ws.Range(Cells(Button_cell_row,3), Cells(Button_cell_row,8)).Copy _ ' For example you need to copy from 3rd column to 8th column...
    Destination:=Target.Cells(i,1) ' ... on the first empty row, from column 1
End If

Set ws = Nothing
Set Target = Nothing

End Sub
```

This wasn't tested and may not work. But you get the idea :) For the "Remove" Sub, it is gonna be very similar.

Comment: thanks! well that made sense & would solve the problem, but I have no clue how to implement it! I like the idea of being able to add a +  and - button to ever row as this would eliminate the need for any major customization Right now say there is this for example

PART#     DESC    LINK(website)    LIST COST   YOUR COST   QTY

for each tab there may be many products. Ideally, if you press ADD it would copy that row (columns A, B, E, F) and paste them onto the PO tab (in the order F, A, B, E)...and if you press REMOVE, it deletes the that row from the PO.